# Can't set full height for flexbox child , any help would be appretiated HTML CSS SASS Web Design

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to create a movies app with similar layout to that of youtube, I used the body as a flex parent and (nav and main) as flex children, I already went through some similar questions in *Stackoverflow* however none of them solved my problem

**an image of the result**
[image]

**here's my code :**

````
```https://codepen.io/userahmad2001/pen/poaKXBz```
````

Comment: hey i'd love to help out, could you give me a picture of what its supposed to look like? like something super quick in MS Paint would help :)

Comment: Please put your code as text, not a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I understand what you're saying,

(If this is completely wrong let me know an I'll update it!)

you need to add a height to the body, perhaps a min-height would help

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh; 
}
```

this sets the height to be ATLEAST the the height of the viewport.

Take a look,
https://codepen.io/looskie-the-flexboxer/pen/abqjOge